# Vue element-plus blur or disable focus after click component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, element-plus

I have a form with ref="form" and some elements in the form, like this:

```
<el-form :model="form" :rules="rules" ref="form" label-width="120px">
<el-form-item label="reason" prop="reason">
            <el-select
              v-model="form.reason"
              //ref="reason" try use this but doesnt work
              filterable
              remote
              reserve-keyword
              placeholder="test"
              :remote-method="remoteMethod"
              :loading="loading"
            >
              <el-option
                v-for="item in options"
                :key="item.value"
                :label="item.name"
                :value="item.value"
                @click="check_exist_variables(item)"
              ></el-option>
            </el-select></el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

I try set ref to item for change focus component after click on that like that:

```
check_exist_variables: function (item) {
      //...
      this.$refs.form.reason.blur();
      // or 
      this.$refs.reason.blur();
    },
```

After click on el-option keep focus on el-option.
What am i do wrong?

upd: this.$refs.select_comment.focus(); is work but blur still doesnt

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you want to achieve? It seems to me meaningless to do blur() after clicking the option. I have created JS Fiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/enmf58cd/. It works without errors. But it does not make any sense to me., what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need that after clicking on select, the focus is removed from the field, since when the field is selected and alt + atb, the component expands to the floor of the screen if it has 10+ options

Comment: You could move focus to the next input field like it's done here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26267067/2487565

Comment: @Tolbxela yeah, that's exactly what I did :)